# Almacenamiento de variables en contador (for)

Tags: c++

Tengo que hacer un programa que saca el promedio de notas de un alumno, con un contador for, pero a la hora de ejecutarlo y ir mostrando los valores que se quedan almacenados en las variables, me sale un numero o conjunto de numeros con letras que no comprendo. Entonces si me podrían aportar alguna solución o un aporte para comprender esto mejor se los agradecería.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

float nota,nota1,nota2,nota3,nota4,nota5,resultado;

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
 cout<<"Ingrese la nota: "<<endl;
 cin>>nota; cout<<endl;
 if (i==0){
     nota = nota1;
     cout<<"La nota1 es: "<<nota1<<endl;;
 }
else if (i==1){
    nota = nota2;
    cout<<"La nota2 es: "<<nota2<<endl;;
}
else if (i==2){
    nota = nota3;
    cout<<"La nota 3 es: "<<nota3<<endl;;
}
else if (i==3){
    nota = nota4;
    cout<<"La nota 4 es: "<<nota4<<endl;;
}
else if (i==4){
    nota = nota5;
    cout<<"La nota 5 es: "<<nota5<<endl;;
}
}

resultado = ((nota1+nota2+nota3+nota4+nota5) / 5);
cout<<"El promedio es: "<<resultado;


    return 0;
}
```

Esto es lo que se ve, cuando ejecuto el programa.

```
Ingrese la nota: 
5.0

La nota1 es: 8.99963e-039
Ingrese la nota:         
4.0

La nota2 es: 5.88745e-039
Ingrese la nota:
3.0

La nota 3 es: 5.8422e+032
Ingrese la nota:
3.0

La nota 4 es: 8.99953e-039
Ingrese la nota:
3.0

La nota 5 es: nan
El promedio es: nan
```

Comment: es porque no tienes un valor en `nota5`, te ha faltado ingresar algun valor al correr tu programa, asi el valor de `nota5` no es `nan` y  tu suma te saldra un `float`

Comment: Los números aparentemente aleatorios son porque imprimes una variable sin inicializar. Cuando declaras una variable, está tiene basura. Y no son "cosas que no entiendes" simplemente está interpretando la basura como el número `8.99963 x 10^-39` (expresado en notación científica).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los valores que describes como "*números con letras*" son la notación científica de números en coma flotante cuando el valor es muy grande o muy pequeño para ser representado de manera significativa con representación tradicional, por ejemplo:

- `8.99963e-039` es 8,99963×10<sup>-39</sup> que sería un 8 con treinta y nueve ceros a su izquierda<sup>1</sup>.
- `5.88745e-039` es 5,88745e×10<sup>-39</sup> que sería un 5 con treinta y nueve ceros a su izquierda.
- `5.8422e+032` es 5,8422×10<sup>32</sup> que sería un 58422 con veintiocho ceros a su derecha.
- `8.99953e-039` es 8,99953×10<sup>-39</sup> que sería un 8 con treinta y nueve ceros a su izquierda.

Si estos números significan poco para ti, es porque realmente tienen poco sentido... son el resultado de mostrar por pantalla un número en coma flotante que no ha sido inicializado<sup>2</sup>, cosa que haces con todas las notas:

```
float nota,nota1,nota2,nota3,nota4,nota5,resultado;
// NINGUNA de las variables anteriores es inicializada,
// por lo tanto TODAS tendrán valores indeterminados.

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout<<"Ingrese la nota: "<<endl;
    cin >> nota; cout << endl;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Guardas en 'nota' el valor leído por la consola pero...
    if (i == 0) {
        nota = nota1;
/*      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Sobrescribes el valor guardado en 'nota' con
                                       el valor guardado en 'nota1' que
                                       es un valor indeterminado porque
                                       'nota1' no ha sido inicializada. */
         cout << "La nota1 es: " << nota1 << endl;;
/*            Imprimes 'nota1' ---> ^^^^^
              que tiene un valor indeterminado porque
              'nota1' no ha sido inicializada. */
    }
    else if (i == 1) {
        nota = nota2;
/*      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Sobrescribes el valor guardado en 'nota' con
                                       el valor guardado en 'nota2' que
                                       es un valor indeterminado porque
                                       'nota2' no ha sido inicializada. */

        cout << "La nota2 es: " << nota2 << endl;;
/*           Imprimes 'nota2' ---> ^^^^^
             que tiene un valor indeterminado porque
             'nota2' no ha sido inicializada. */
    }
...
...
...
```

Si sólo quieres calcular la media de cinco valores, no necesitas guardar los cinco valores individualmente, puedes acumularlos y dividir por cinco al final:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    using namespace std;

    float notas = .0f; // Inicializamos a cero

    // Variables con nombres comprensibles y autoexplicativos
    for (int indice = 0; indice != 5; ++indice) {
        float nota; // No inicializamos porque sobrescribiremos su valor
        cout << "Ingrese la nota " << indice << ":\n";
        cin >> nota; cout << endl;

        // Acumulamos el valor leido
        notas += nota;
    }

    cout << "El promedio es: " << notas / 5;

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVC7bgJBDKzZr3BIkwglkAcNB0gpUtCkTJXG7Blkac@@7APlIb79snsHEZ3tmfGMbdv2zjqUfddds1iXaoIla4iesFkbwxKhQZabW/g1ZpQCyx4EGwotWoIQ6yqPd04xgmjEACu4n@0qmE5hI2wZHf9gowEQLHnN5Iy8o2fcOgpgVbKu2fq@blpPErhHvgFTVPpqHVuMfNCQfdTDTYnEUnO2X8GsOtdXK5hXMJkMbYk7usjVB3rTTL7M1Kr/TPkKLf7W85Y9lXlIcECnPq@wmiIslzDeyD6TCBz2C2Fcpifvgi8@ZFwVAQus1yfTs5qkduVR5fgXm5rken9ygw844lozPLxwshrkZnTMmv8Erw5arw3VrEBhMSQYFNN8e6Z6islLfoo5dt2DeTRP5tnMzR8)</kbd>.

---

###### <sup>1</sup>0,000000000000000000000000000000000000000899963.

###### <sup>2</sup>Los números no inicializados tienen un valor indeterminado.

Comment: Excelente explicacion, muy completa. Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicarme tan detalladamente. Ahora si comprendo mucho mejor el dilema que tenía!!!!